# Is this proof correct $A=\bar{A} \implies A$ is closed

Tags: general-topology

To prove $A=\bar{A} \implies A$ is closed
In order to prove the above implication,it is sufficient to prove that i
$A=\bar{A} \implies A^C$ is open meaning $A^C$ is an element of the topology
Since $A=\bar{A}$ means that every element of A is a contact point of A

Now suppose $x \in A^C \implies ,x$ is not a contact point of $A$ as all the contact points of $A$ are contained in $A$.
Therefore $\exists$ an open set $V_x$ s.t $x \in V_x$ and $V_x \cap A=\phi $

Now $\bigcup_{x \in A^C} V_x \in T$ where $T$ is the topology on $X$ because the arbitrary union of open sets is open and it belongs to the topology $T$

But clearly $A^C= \bigcup_{x \in A^C} V_x$. This is evident because the open sets we chose had the following property
$$V_x \cap A=\phi $$
This implies $A^C$ is open $\implies A$ is closed

Answer (score 3):

Yes your proof is ok. Actually following your proof there is an alternate definition that $\bar A$ is the smallest closed set containing A. So you will get your answer readily from there.